# where to edit mysql fulltext stopword lists?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

i saw the fulltext stopword lists of mysql is in english. That's a bit weird considering mysql is used all over the world...

Anyway i lowered the ft_min_word_len to 3, so i need to add the common words in my language to this lists.

Someone can tell me where i can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

> To override the default stopword
>   list, set the ft_stopword_file system
>   variable. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server
>   System Variables”.) The variable value
>   should be the path name of the file
>   containing the stopword list, or the
>   empty string to disable stopword
>   filtering. The server looks for the
>   file in the data directory unless an
>   absolute path name is given to specify
>   a different directory. After changing
>   the value of this variable or the
>   contents of the stopword file, restart
>   the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT
>   indexes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html