# Against not returning score

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, match-against

There is something wrong with this query? This one works sometimes and sometimes not. For example with the word 'seven' it doesn't return any score, but i know that it appears on 29 rows at least in the body however it return as score 0.

With other words it work ok but not with this one. Anyone know why or have a different solution to sort it by relevance?

```
   SELECT *, 
         ( (MATCH(articles.name) AGAINST('seven'))*5 +
           (MATCH(articles.subtitle) AGAINST('seven'))*3 + 
           (MATCH(articles.body) AGAINST('seven'))) AS search_score 
     FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN matches ON articles.match=matches.id 
 ORDER BY search_score DESC
```

EDIT: I noticed that 'seven' is a stop word. There is other way to do this? [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

Comment: Have you checked each separately?  SQL doesn't add NULL well...

Answer (score 0):

Add COALESCE(value,0) around each score.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
If the word is too common, i.e. occurs in 50%+ of the rows, MySQL considers it a STOP-word and will not match against it.
Then there's the stop-word list *(which you've already noticed)*
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

**Solution**
This answer: [where to edit mysql fulltext stopword lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685252/where-to-edit-mysql-fulltext-stopword-lists/4685382#4685382)
Tells you how to override/replace the default stop word list.

Here's the link to the MySQL docs page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Disable them is not an option in this case.

Comment: @Sein Kraft, If you cannot alter the stop-word list then I think you're out of luck as far as `match against` is concerned.