# MySQL FULLTEXT search on part of the column text?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am interesting in applying `fulltext search` on a column which contains the complete `path` to a document. For instance below:

```
Dir1/Dir2/Countries/regions/Countries regions list.pdf
```

Now the question is if it is possible to do FULLTEXT Search only on the filename part of the column `path`? Or what would you suggest to achieve it?

I can't include complete PATH field in the search as the directory names could disturb the relevancy in the end. The only meaningful and required information in the path field is the filename. Is there any way without creating new column for `filenames`?

I MUST apply fulltext as I am also searching on other fields from other tables in the query.

Any sort of help is highly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited number of directory names (in PATH), then you can add those names in [stopwords list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685252/where-to-edit-mysql-fulltext-stopword-lists) to edit the stopwords list.

Comment: Those directory names are too much to be added manually in stopwords list.

Comment: Secondly, some of the directory names are actually keywords that could be used for searching within filename. So this isn't doable. Any other idea?